# wmic process - capture in variable

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I want to capture the processID in a variable but I get an error, thanks ...

```
wmic process where name="notepad.exe" get ProcessId

ProcessID

7948

for /f %%a IN ('wmic process where name="notepad.exe" get ProcessId') do set "MYVAL=%%a"
echo %MYVAL%

notepad.exe - Invalid alias verb
```

Comment: `("wmic process where name=^"notepad.exe^" get ProcessId")` gets rid of the error, but it is not assigning the process ID to MYVAL.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to do this with DOS batch?  Doing it with Powershell or VBScript would be a piece of cake.  DOS batch is about the most difficult thing you can use for things like this...

Comment: what do the ^ mean in bach sctripts?

Comment: http://www.psteiner.com/2008/12/using-caret-in-windows-batch-files.html

Comment: Google "what does caret mean in dos batch" for more exciting reading.

Answer (score 3):

try like this

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a IN (`wmic process where "name='notepad.exe'" get ProcessId`) do @echo %%a
```

**EDIT**

to get the pid:

```
for /f "skip=1 usebackq" %%a IN (`wmic process where "name='notepad.exe'" get ProcessId`) do (

    rem @echo %%a
    if "%%a" neq "" set "pid=%%~a"

)
```

the equal sign must be put in double quotes because is one of default delimiters in batch syntax.